# Regex if then not

Tags: regex, if-statement, conditional-statements

I try to implement a regex that should validate the following rules :

- if the string contains 'Hello' or 'Goodbye'
- the string cannot contains 'World' or 'MyLove'
- else
- the string must contains 'World' or 'MyLove'

I tried severals implementation with no success. Here is the last one :

```
(?(?=(\bHello\b|\bGoodbye\b)(?!World|MyLove)(World|MyLove)))
```

Some example of the expecting result :

- Hello, how are you MyLove ? false
- Goodbye my dear ! true
- Nice to meet you ! false
- Nice to meet you MyLove ! true

Thank you in advance for your help.

Raphaël

Comment: Don't try to use a single regex for complex conditions, you end up either pulling your hair out or being insulted by certain high-rep opinionated SO users :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your regex flavor you could use something like:

```
(?x)                               # allow whitespace and comments
^                                  # anchor at start of string
(?(?= .* \b(Hello|Goodbye)\b )     # if
  (?! .* \b(World|MyLove)\b )      # then
| (?= .* \b(World|MyLove)\b )      # else
)
```

But it may be more clearly written in your language directly. For example in Perl:

```
/\b(Hello|Goodbye)\b/ ?
!/\b(World|MyLove)\b/ :
/\b(World|MyLove)\b/;
```